# Use awk to do: if value in $2 of row n+1 = value+1 in $2 of row n, print $1, $2 from row n and average $3 from n and n+1

Tags: unix, awk

I am trying to figure out a way to compare values in the 2nd column of a long tab-delimited file. Take a value in the 2nd column of every row: if the value of the next row (in the 2nd column) is one greater than the previous one, I would like to average the value of the third column for each of them. For example:

```
ABC 111 9
ABC 114 4
ABC 115 5
ABC 117 5
```

And get:

```
ABC 111 9
ABC 114 4.5
ABC 117 5
```

This is way above my very low-level awk abilities.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For your provided example could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
{
  if(($NF-prev)==1 && prev){
     print val1,val2,(prev+$NF)/2;
     val1=val2=prev="";
     next}
  else if(FNR>1 && prev){
     print val1,val2,prev}
}
{
  prev=$NF;
  val1=$1;
  val2=$2
}
END{
  if(FNR>1 && prev){
    print val1,val2,prev}
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to coalesce and average entire sequences where subsequent lines are one greater than the previous, the following snippet shows one way:

```
count == 0 {                                # For start of first sequence.
    count=1;                                #   Set count for first sequence.
    last1=$1; first2=$2; last2=$2; sum=$3;  #   Store starting values.
    next                                    #   Go on to next line.
}
last2 + 1 == $2 {                           # Else for lines WITHIN sequence.
    count++;                                #   Increment count.
    last1=$1; first2=$2; last2=$2; sum+=$3; #   Adjust values.
    next                                    #   On to next line.
}
{                                           # Else this is a NEW sequence.
    print last1" "first2" "sum/count;       #   Print last sequence.
    count=1;                                #   Reset count for new sequence.
    last1=$1; first2=$2; last2=$2; sum=$3   #   Set starting values.
}
END {                                       # Handle final sequence here.
    if (count != 0) {                       #   Only if there were items.
        print last1" "first2" "sum/count
    }
}
```

With that script, the following input data:

```
ABC 111 9
ABC 113 4
ABC 114 4
ABC 115 5
ABC 117 5
```

generates:

```
ABC 111 9
ABC 113 4.33333
ABC 117 5
```

The way it works is to *not* print details about each line immediately, but to *store* the details of the line until the next line is evaluated.

If the next line is part of the same sequence, its details are rolled into previous details and we carry on.

If the next line is the start of a *new* sequence, we then output the previous sequence (rolled up and averaged, of course) then store this next line as the start of a sequence.

That means we need an `END` block to process the final sequence since there's no next line to force a sequence break.

---

Note that this does not take into account a changing field #1 since there was no mention of that in the question. To do that it's a simple matter of detecting that *before* checking the "this-field-2 is one greater than last-field-2" (the second block above) and moving on to a new sequence:

```
last1!=$1 {                                 # Changed field 1 is new sequence.
    print last1" "first2" "sum/count;       #   Print last sequence.
    count=1;                                #   Reset count for new sequence.
    last1=$1; first2=$2; last2=$2; sum=$3;  #   Set starting values.
    next                                    #   Get next line.
}
```